# Bad character set in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, character-encoding, keytool

I am trying to execute

> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
>   %HOMEPATH%.android\debug.keystore

this command in Android Stuido 3.0.1 terminal with Windows 10 english language.

It asks me for password, and after I give it, it responds me with this:

> ╔╔   ║ 0j10═╚U╝═U┼┐┼⎺┬┼10═╚UU┼┐┼⎺┬┼10═╚U╝U┼┐┼⎺┬┼10═╚U╝
>   450515143623Z0┘10═╚U╝═U┼┐┼⎺┬┼10═╚UU┼┐┼⎺┬┼10═╚U╝U┼┐┼⎺┬┼10═╚U╝ ╔╔╔║ ╚é╔
>   0é╔ 
>                Unknown10
>                         ═╚U╝╚║P▒┴␊┌0é╔"0 ╗é╔╔ ÅH÷╚║î┴Θ@±í┼
>                    2:ƒ
>                       ö∞␍␋6δV▀É╡8+␤º@ú⎽U╩▐¼₧][û╫ìÅ≤XÆ├φ╟⎽A┬,┬╗±ë.≠,ô┤&:·±
>                                                                          (≡■⎻4◆ù\ôP├≠╔±σáL␋0≡╠╤ì98<5Θ9é╦Γ£7␍⌐█Ö≈╪┐┬␤Æ≤6¬┤╩á¼Ä
>   µ╟(Ωïö◆╣⌐µ╣␌F2╔σµ┼S≡╚9úà/≤◆╦␉*ó_(␌┤±»┬@[▀∙-P┴Ü╔4┬╢27¥┤√┌êΦ:≥J┌ƒ┤Ä╣█┘ê┼≠╚Θóσ5/U╨└╝Ü9$╒╝∩H␤6┴║ß╫±┘) <Å£≥┤╤\·ï▐ú¢ÿ::┼]╗╚╔
>   ╔ú!00═╚U╝ ½TO/$J␋ï╒┬Bé▒╕┌╔π╕─␉Bª╦╙│=D┤@±┴8┐≠5.;@└P3ê␌╒%╒ ·:*Gƒ∙Ω
>   2░╓┘╫┼␊9ÆQHE&HV8─¿␊═ª2+±∙ò≤ì¢▐ó°⎻óΩ≈
>   ·╗¬»╡P·╠1º'X∞E≠WNêï╔,T6√Æ╬îÑ┌\▓Cä⎺»╧î╬\¿Nù¢K Sφ◆%µ¬û╤≤σ▒óP ùN▒
>   εR£╤^ñ┴≥âSD·╬7¢D2▐╕ü╫⌠╠@H«╗⎻░ö6º¼^ⁿä∞ñCá┤─≥┼╬≥$Ä␌├.␉M8°C│▀±◆
>   F:\A┼␍⎼⎺␋␍\F▒␌␊␉⎺⎺┐A┤├␤>┐␊≤├⎺⎺┌ -␊│⎻⎺⎼├␌␊⎼├ -▒┌␋▒⎽ ▒┼␍⎼⎺␋␍␍␊␉┤±┐␊≤
>   -┐␊≤⎽├⎺⎼␊ C:\U⎽␊⎼⎽\␊⎽├*⎽.▒┼␍⎼⎺␋␍\␍␊␉┤±.┐␊≤⎽├⎺⎼␊ E┼├␊⎼ ┐␊≤⎽├⎺⎼␊ ⎻▒⎽⎽┬⎺⎼␍: ┐␊≤├⎺⎺┌ ␊⎼⎼⎺⎼: ┘▒┴▒.␋⎺.IOE│␌␊⎻├␋⎺┼: ┐␊≤⎽├⎺⎼␊ ⎻▒⎽⎽┬⎺⎼␍ ┬▒⎽
>   ␋┼␌⎺⎼⎼␊␌├

I tried couple of decoder, but resulless. 
I tried to get hash key for adding facebook auth in android app. If there is any other method of gettin this key, please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solve next way:
1. Download openSSL
2. Make a path in variables
3. Create an SSL keytool request

> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
>   "C:\Users\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl"
>   sha1 -binary | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl" base64

Comment: Congrats. Thanks for sharing. Keep it up.

Answer (score 0):

Try the command below to get your key alias

```
keytool -list -v -keystore <name>.keystore
```